# Share folder with all users in company

Tags: onedrive-for-business, onedrive

We have one one drive account with some folders with manuals,

I want this folder to be shared for new users example so i want to make a script that shares this folder for me with powershell for example?

Can some tell me how i can do this, i prefer that user doesn't get a link but it just added to shared folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just move this to a SharePoint Online Communication site then add 'Everyone except external users' to the Viewers group?

Comment: No i don't want to use different tool, it must stay easy an the same for the user, i don't want to use two tools. Share point and one drive. I want to keep one drive

Comment: OneDrive isn't designed for this type of sharing. But you can add 'Everyone except external users' or use your Shared with everyone folder in ODfB to allow everyone to view it.

Comment: You can map SharePoint Document Libraries in the OneDrive application as well. @TrevorSeward is right, you should be using SharePoint for this. Keep OneDrive for personal files.

Comment: This works great thank you verry mutch